# javascript function onclick must click twice -_- why so?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page(it is an faq page for a web site) such that when a user click on a div (e.g. #question01) there's a new div that appears below it. Really easy but the thing is that with my function, when you click the first time, nothing appears, then another click and there you go. My #faqAnswer01 has now a "unhide" class which is set to display:block; (.hide = display:none;)

So here are my two question :

1- Why do I have to click twice for my function to get executed?

2- How can I fix my code so that it works after just one click?

HTML CODE

```
<div id="faqContainer">

   <div id="question01" onclick="showAnswer('faqAnswer01','imgArrow01');">Here's a question?<img src="public/images/gt.png" class="imgArrow" id="imgArrow01"></div>
        <div id="faqAnswer01" class="faqAnswerDiv hide">bla bla bla</div>

   <div id="question02" onclick="showAnswer('faqAnswer02','imgArrow02');">Another question here? <img src="public/images/gt.png" class="imgArrow" id="imgArrow02"></div>
    <div id="faqAnswer02" class="faqAnswerDiv hide">answer here.</div>

</div>
```

My function:

```
function showAnswer(idAnswer , idImg) {
    if (document.getElementById(idImg).src == "http://www.cbifinance.org/public/images/gt.png") {
        document.getElementById(idImg).src = "http://www.cbifinance.org/public/images/gt90.png";
        document.getElementById(idAnswer).className = 'faqAnswerDiv unhide';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(idImg).src = "http://www.cbifinance.org/public/images/gt.png";
        document.getElementById(idAnswer).className = 'faqAnswerDiv hide';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `image.src` to the full URL and it should work.

The reason this would work is that your `src` is `public/images/gt.png` even though when it loads the image it finds it correctly, the `src` is still `public/images/gt.png`.

So the first time you click, it runs into the else statement, and sets the `src` to the full absolute url. Then you click again and it changed the `src` to what you expected the first time. The same goes for the `class`, its adding the `hide` class to the image, which it already has but the second time it adds `show`. The code is functioning correctly, the if statement is just wrong.

Comment: Great! Now I know what's wrong in this. Thanks you. I tried your version but now nothing is working. Is the .src must start with full absolute url?

Comment: Don't see why it wouldn't work. Aslong as the image.src and the if statement.src are the same text it should work.

Comment: .src only gives absolute url path. Even if I put a if statement with my img.src == 'public/images/gt.png', it will never gives that. What I did to fix my problem is that I simply put a full url in my <img src=""> :)!

Comment: Huh. I would have thought it would give you whatever you has in the src originally. Not what it resolves it too. Cool :) glad I could help matt

Comment: Updated my answer to the correct solution as per your comment!

Comment: @iLikePrograms, I am giving full path in my src. though it is going in the else part.

Comment: @matt_bois, full URL means? I have put path like: https://... but not working. Always go in else for first click

Answer (score 2):

Because first time the `src` is not what your `if` is checking for

```
src="public/images/gt.png"
```

VS

```
src="http://www.cbifinance.org/public/images/gt.png"
```

Then on the first click you set it to that. And then for the second time your `if` condition is met.

Comment: I am giving full path in src to match with like https://domainName/images/imageName. But it is going in else part always.